# Analytics tracking, same URL different ID

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Our online presentation software generates an URL for each presentation which was created, such as [this example](https://view.shadow.ly/5ae08e50128bd43e60d62802).

We can track that URL in our Google Analytics Account without any problems.

My question is, can any random user of our platform track that same URL, since it is his/hers property, using his/her Google Analytics Account? Thank you

Comment: The link you've provided doesn't work for me.

Comment: But the key here is, can they edit the HTML of their URL? If not, then the only way they can use GA against it would be if you prompted for their GA id and included it for them. e.g. www.payloadz.com (which I use) does this for its customers.